# My page will be treated as an iframe content and i want to remove the scroll

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I have created a page that will be used as a source URL for an iframe on different pages on different sites, as an advertisement widget.
I want to remove the scrolling on the iframe and load the full content without scroll.

I have tried this with the iframe tag but which is not recommended

Comment: share with us your code please

Answer (score 0):

If you content is of a fixed size, then set the size of the iframe to match this, if the content can vary in size, checkout iframe-resizer on npm.